# MySQL - SELECT the name that comes first alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql

I have started to learn MySQL.

Here is the table `world`:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|    name     | continent |  area   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| Afghanistan | Asia      | 652230  |
| Albania     | Europe    | 2831741 |
| Algeria     | Africa    | 28748   |
| ...         | ...       | ...     |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

I need:

> List each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically

The result of SELECT must be:

```
+---------------+---------------------+
|   continent   |         name        |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Africa        | Algeria             |
| Asia          | Afghanistan         |
| Caribbean     | Antigua and Barbuda |
| Eurasia       | Armenia             |
| Europe        | Albania             |
| North America | Belize              |
| Oceania       | Australia           |
| South America | Argentina           |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a simple aggegation:

```
SELECT continent, MIN(name) AS name
FROM world 
GROUP BY continent
ORDER by continent
```

Comment: and simpler than mine :)

Comment: You don't need ORDER BY statement for this.

Comment: You may not need it, but the OP expected an ordered result set and even if the result is currently returned in the right order it may change anytime.

Answer (score 13):

If it's an Exercise from [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial), than IMO it should look something like this:

```
select continent, name from world x
where name = (select name 
                  from world y 
                  where  x.continent =  y.continent 
                  order by name asc 
                  limit 1)
```

P.S. I study SQL from there now and this post helped me. Thanks to @Parado!)

Update: I've found this [site](http://weeblike.weebly.com/sum-and-count.html) with answers. Useful if stack.

Comment: why `select top 1` in the inner select is not working?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
select distinct  w.continent, 
                 (select w2.name 
                  from world w2 
                  where  w.continent =  w2.continent 
                  order by name asc 
                  limit 1) name 
from world w
order by w.continent
```

Answer (score 3):

The SqlZoo solution would better look like this:

```
SELECT continent, name FROM world x
WHERE name <= ALL
  (SELECT name FROM world y WHERE y.continent=x.continent)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  distinct x.continent , x.name
FROM world x ,world y 
WHERE x.name = (SELECT y.name FROM world y
 WHERE y.continent=x.continent order by y.name asc limit 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this sql :

```
select distinct continent, 
      (select name 
       from world y where y.continent = x.continent limit 1 ) as name 
from world x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT continent,
       name
FROM world x
WHERE name=
    (SELECT name
     FROM world y
     WHERE x.continent=y.continent
     ORDER BY name
     LIMIT 1)
```

This is correlated/ synchronous query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select continent, name
from
(select continent, name, rank() over(partition by continent order by name) r1
from world) a
where a.r1 = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select distinct continent, name from world x 
where name <=All (Select name from world y where x.continent=y.continent)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it will fix the issue. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

```
select continent, name from world group by continent order by name
```

Comment: This does NOT add anything to the already selected answer and it does not answer the question: it will only order the results while the OP want only one per continent.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
SELECT continent, name FROM world ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: That's going to list every single country in the world.

Answer (score -3):

If you need list each continent alphabetically, you have use

```
     SELECT * from world ORDER by continent
```

But, If you nedd list each country your have use

```
     SELECT * from world ORDER by name
```

Comment: This is going to list every single country in the world.

Comment: no, This is going to list the country or the continet in the bd, The not specify any restriction